# How to write unit test for attribute modal validations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit, mstest

When I call the actual API from local source the attribute validations working great. But when I call the actual API from unit test, the attribute validations will not call. Directly goes to the api implementations.

Refer the c# Code:

```
Public string AddTwoNumbers([Required] int num1, [(Required), (ValidFormat)] int num2) 
{
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
```

Modal attribute custom validation which is - Required, ValidFormat (Created class and done the validation)

But When I am calling this API from unit test, those validations will not work.

How can we write unit test case for those validation?

Comment: I am guessing your unit test will call the _method_, not the _endpoint_. The difference being that calling the endpoint, the request goes through all the host framework hoops including all the middleware. Calling the method directly will exactly do just that, without middleware and host framework.

Comment: So, what do you want to test here? That the result is the expected for inputs _in the expected range_? That invalid inputs will be detected as such? Or do you want to test if validation is applied at all?

Comment: What I want here is When calling the AddTwoNumbers API with null or invalid format from unit test case, it will working.

public void Test_invalidnumbers(){   _ctx.AddTwoNumbers(10, -98);   }

I have validate to allow only positive numbers. In above unit test scenario I have validate with negative numbers. But in this scenario, it will run instead of throwing error message.